# concatenating convolutions with different strides in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, concatenation, conv-neural-network, convolution

I am attempting to reproduce a CNN from a research paper using tensoflow. Here is the whole architecture of the CNN, but I am mainly focused on the Reduction A section.[image: Whole Architecture]

[image: Reduction A]

I am wondering if I have spotted a problem with the research paper. As you can see in Reduction A, 3 layers are concatenated. However, 2 of those layers use a stride of 2. Therefore, when concatenating the tensor along the 4th axis(number of channels), the right most layer does not have the same depth, width and height as the other 2 layers. I am aware that I could use padding to fix this, but there is no mention of this in the paper. **Do you believe this research paper has a mistake? Should the right most path of reduction A also use a stride of 2?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering that all the other reductions and inceptions have matching strides, it seems like the paper made a mistake. I suppose the 3x3(384) convolution was supposed to have a stride of 2, since this convolution increases the channel size.

Comment: Thank you! If you had a moment, would you mind explaining what the "2x," "4x," "8x," and "16x" represented next to the deconvolutions

Comment: @DevinHaslam The numbers correspond to the difference in resolution between the input resolution (MxN) and the reduced resolution after the corresponding blocks due to the strides. However I can't tell how those deconvolutions look like from those pictures alone, but the numbers are equal to the resolution amount that has to be "restored" by the deconvolutions.

Comment: So when I perform the 2x deconvolution, I begin with a tensor of the shape of (?, 16, 16, 4, 192); this stands for (batch, width, depth, height, channels). However, I still need to figure out a 5d filter(depth, width, height, inchannels, outchannels) and a 1d output shape. The research paper does not mention any of these values. Is knowing that the deconvolution is "2x" enough information to derive the filter and output shape? Thanks again, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @DevinHaslam there is not enough information in the pictures to tell the deconvolution filter size or the output channel amount.

Comment: I have been working on this problem for quite some time. I am not really understanding the arithmetic behind a transpose deconvolution. Sorry if I am asking for too much, but would you mind taking a look at this question? No one has answered it for a week. Thanks, and I understand if you don't answer it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46590920/deconvolutions-transpose-convolutions-with-tensorflow

Comment: Could you explain why there is not enough information in the image to find the output channel amount for the deconvolutions?

Comment: any chance you could help me out again. I'm so close to having this project finished. Thank you! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47638633/tensorflow-neural-network-prediction-is-always-the-same