# initializing a large tf.variable produces an error

Tags: python, tensorflow

The following lines of code produces an error specifying that the tenor cannot be parsed based on the prototype (printed immediately after sess.run(...) is executed).

```
 w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.,shape=[16,16,7,3298,3298]))
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

However, these very similar lines of code work (but takes a long time).

```
 w = tf.Variable(tf.constant(1.,shape=[8,8,7,2338,2338]))
 with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
```

**Is there a maximum shape size for a tf.Variable?**

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Comment: "cannot parse tensor from proto: dtype: DT_FLOAT" I recently read that tensors cannot be larger than 2gb. Do you think that this is the problem here? In my case w is a filter for a transpose convolution. How would I go about splitting the tensor into smaller ones and still use it as a filter size?